# Jenkins - how to run a single stage using 2 agents

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a script that acts as a "test driver" (TD). That is, it drives test operations on a "system under test" (SUT). When I run my test framework script (`tfs.sh`) on my TD, it takes a SUT as an argument. The manual workflow looks like this:

```
TD ~ $ ./tfs.sh --sut=<IP of SUT>
```

I want to have a cluster of SUTs (they will have different OSes, and each will repeat a few times), and a few TDs (like, 4 or 5, so driving tests won't be a bottleneck, actually executing them will be).

---

I don't know the Jenkins primitive with which to accomplish this. I would like it if a Jenkins stage could simply be invoked with 2 agents. One would obviously be the TD, that's what would actually run the script. And the other would be the SUT. Jenkins would manage locking & resource contention like this.

As a workaround, I could simply have all my SUTs entirely unmanaged by Jenkins, and manually implement locking of the SUTs so 2 different TDs don't try to grab the same one. But why re-invent the wheel? And besides, I'd rather work on a Jenkins plugin to accomplish this than on a manual solution.

---

How can I run a single Jenkins stage on 2 (or more) agents?

Comment: To answer your question. Yes, you can execute the same stage on multiple Agents. So simply you want to execute TDs in multiple Jenkins agents and TD should be pointed to the correct SUTs? Here SUTs are just servers that execute tests?

Comment: @ycr SUTs are servers that execute tests, yes. A cluster of SUTs exists. I want to be able to run the test stage on a TD and allow it to use 1 or more SUTs for the run. 1 stage of testing, 2+ agents (a TD and some SUTs)

Comment: I think you can build on top of the example I provided. I added some additional comments there.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you have a static list of SUTs and you want Jenkins to start the TDs by allocating SUTs for each TD. I'm assuming TDs and SUTs have a one-to-one relationship. Following is a very simple example of how you can achieve what you need.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {        
      stage('parallel-run') {
              steps {
                  script {
                      try {
                          def tests = getTestExecutionMap()
                          parallel tests
                      } catch (e) {
                          currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                      }
                  }
              }
      }
  }
}

def getTestExecutionMap() {
    
    def tests = [:]
    def sutList = ["IP1", "IP2" , "IP3"]

    int count = 0
    for(String ip : sutList) {
      tests["TEST${count}"] = {
            node {
                stage("TD with SUT ${ip}") {
                    script {
                        sh "./tfs.sh --sut=${ip}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        count++
    }    
    return tests
}
```

The above pipeline will result in the following.

[image]

Further if you wan to select the agent you want to run the TD. You can specify the name of the agent in the node block. `node(NAME) {...}` . You can improve the Agent selection criteria accordingly. For example you can check how many Jenkins executors are idling for a given Agent and then decide how many TDs you will start there.

Comment: So we manually implement taking ownership of a SUT with the `getTestExecutionMap` function. This is a nice workaround, but it will not stop a second invocation of this pipeline from taking the same SUT as the first one. Jenkins won’t assign an executor twice because it has some more intelligence around assigning executors & agents to jobs. I want to take advantage of that built in resource contention.

Comment: @AriSweedler Although the tests will run in parallel. For Jenkins the entire run is a single build. And you can always disable concurrent builds for the pipeline. Once disabled if the same pipeline is executed again it will be added to the build queue. If you want to do advance state management you may have to persist the states to somewhere accessible and allocate SUTs based on that.